# How to compare an axios get data(date) with todays date and change the background color if its overdue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, date-comparison

I'm getting an api data as due_On(2018-08-01T00:00:00) using axios and i need to compare that particular date with todays date and my aim is to change the background color of that particular row which is overdue.

The thing is its actually working but the problem is if the first data is a future date it updates the background color as red and if the second data is a previous date it updates everything into green color.

```
    const title = this.props.dataItem[this.props.field];
    var today = new Date(),
        date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();

    const style = {
        backgroundColor: title > date ? "red" : "green",
        color: title > date ? "#000": "#fff"
    };

    return (
        <td style={style}>
           {(this.props.dataItem[this.props.field]).toString()}
        </td>
    );
```

Comment: If you need to compare `date` you can convert them to Unix formats. In JS it is with this `new Date().getTime()`

Comment: Okay....got the result using moment js.